# javascript: building a conditional off of array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

if I have an array like this:

```
thisarray = new Array("this", "that", "theotherthing");
```

how could I go about building a conditional like so:

```
if(thisarray[0] == thisvar && thisarray[1] == thisvar && thisarray[2] == thisvar) { 
    //do something
}
```

the caveat is that I do not know how many items could be in thisarray. I'm a bit stumped as to how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say <code>thisvar</code> 3 times, do you really mean the same one?

Comment: If your array consist of different values, the statement will never be true anyway...

Comment: The way your question is asked, it sounds like the following: How can I check if all values in an array are a specific value? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @c_p - no, sorry, no that's a mistake, it should be thisarray[0] == thisvar1 && thisarray[1] == thisvar2, etc.

Comment: @Pruitlgoe -- if you don't know how many items there are ahead of time, then where are your `thisvar1`, `thisvar2`, etc... coming from? Do you just want to check if two arrays are equal?

Comment: @Ben Lee I know the maximum amount the array can hold, (six) but these will be form selections (for a user to filter results) so it can be any of the six items or all of the six items. Dang, this is a matter of me not posting the right info - thisarray is associative so thisarray[0] would actually be thisarray['id']... so as an example a user could be filtering the data on two items thisarray[id] and thisarray['department'] but next time they could be filtering on 3 items...

Comment: Wow, Pruitlgoe. You ask a question yesterday, didn't like the answers, and so completely edited the question to something completely different, making every single answer below null and void and nonsensical. That's just nasty.

Comment: @boyetboy - where did I post I didn't like the answers...if you look at the edits I admitted that I posted the question incorrectly and then reposted it for clarification, apologized for being initially unclear (several times BTW) and +1 people who answered my initial post...some of the post here pointed me in the right direction so I wrote code that solved my problem and then posted it for critique and to help someone else if they are in the same sit...not sure how that is being nasty whatever...

Comment: Okay guys.  But, seriously, ask a new question, don't drastically alter your current one.  Edits are for adding information or correcting mistakes only.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Javascript 1.6 support, you can do it in one line:

```
if (thisarray.every(function(e) { return (e == thisvar); })) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = true;
for(var i=0; i<thisarray.length && valid; ++i){
    if (thisarray[i] != thisvar)
        valid = false;
}
//use valid
if(valid)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop  to "iterate" through the items in the array, checking the value each time.

```
var result = true;
for(var x=0; x < thisarray.length; x+=1){
    if(thisarray[x] != thisvar){
       result = false;
    }
}
```

`result` will be true if every item of the array equals thisvar, false if there is a mismatch.

Comment: See my edit to the original post, I made a mistake in typing it. Each array item will match a unique var.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function:

```
function all(arr, f) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (!f(arr[i], i)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Then you can call:

```
if (all(thisArray, function(a) { return a === thisvar; })) {
  // all equal
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bit overkill, but it's pretty clean. :)

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE: I mis-read your request to check if any of the elements match, when what you asked for is for all of them to match. I'm leaving my answer here though for reference if you want the condition to be true for any match.*

You could just iterate through the elements with a for loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < thisarray.length; i++) {
    if (thisarray[i] == thisvar) {
        // do something
        break; // so it doesn't repeat if there are multiple matches
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to up vote this, but then I realized that he wants to do something if ALL of them are true, not just one.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am trying to match different array items with different variables, in my OP i messed that up. I won't know how many items might be in the array which is where I am getting stumped...see my edit above...

Answer (score 0):

Just have an array of actual values and an array of expected values and then compare elements. Something like this:

```
function arraysEqual(actual, expected) {
  if (actual.length !== expected.length) { return false; }
  var count = actual.length;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (actual[i] !== expected[i]) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}
```